# Rails: How to store chat conversations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am writing a rails application with conversations between clients and administrators. And i want the administrators respond to questions sent it by clients.

The administrators should be able to see the previous conversations with a reply box.

What is the best way to save these coversations:

- Single table with marks of question and answer and view them as table entries?
- Different tables and simply organise them by time?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Administrator < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages, as: :author
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages, as: :author
end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :chat
end

class Chat < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages
  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :administrator
end
```

If you want to show messages of a particular chat you can do it this way:

```
@chat = Chat.find_by_client_id_and_administrator_id(client_id, administrator_id)
@messages = @chat.messages.order(:created_at)
```

If `client` and `administrator` belong to the same model, for instance `User`, then:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages
end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :chat
end

class Chat < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages
  belongs_to :client, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :administrator, class_name: "User"
end
```